# Dynamically decide the configuration source in startup.cs-ConfigureServices(....)

Tags: c#, .net-core

Just started with .net-core. Questions is also about interfaces and implementation. I want to achieve environment based DI of configuration provider. If the hosting environment is development read from appsettings.json, for production I need to read secrets(api-key and similar stuff) from Azure Key-Vault and other non-secret stuff from appsettings.json.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IHostEnvironment currentEnvironment)
{

if (currentEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
   services.AddTransient<ICustomConfiguration,AppConfiguration>();
else
   services.AddTransient<ICustomConfiguration,MixedConfiguration>();
}
```

I believe we could do it with ConfigureAppConfiguration hook on IHostBuilder. But my boss is  strongly opinionated on achieving this in DI (ConfigureServices(...))

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have in you question will work if you actually want to inject a different service implementation per environment. A good example of this would be if you had a send email service and you want to inject an instance that does not actually send emails but just logs content in dev vs one that actually sends the email in production. Its important to differentiate between the service implementation actually doing something different vs the same functionality using different configuration values such as a connection string.

In the example above, I think what you are really asking is how to vary you configuration settings per environment. Ideally the format of your configuration settings should not change based on environment they would just have different values.

In general the best way is to use a mechanism support by ASP.NET core configuration.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0.

I typically use environment variables to override the base configuration specified.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-prefixed-environment-variables

This works very well if you are developing and running your service using docker containers as it is very easy to specify environment variable configuration overrides in your docker compose configuration. This way you can usually leave a default dev configuration in your containers and then have the individuals deployment environments override specific items like connection string, log levels, etc.

There is a similar override mechanism for secrets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#security-and-user-secrets that I believe can tie into azure key vault stores for non development use cases.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Hopefully this will get you on the right path.